# Template part inside shortcode, unexpected reult

Tags: php, shortcode, get-template-part

I am attempting to call a template part via a shortcode. Ive read all about how to do this over and over on this site and yet after having tried a number of things still am unable to call a simple php echo time string. **The file name is test-one.php**  .Here is what I've tried:

```
function test_2( $attr ) {
    ob_start();
    get_template_part( 'test', 'one' );
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('test2', 'test_2');
```

---

```
function test_2( $attr ) {
    ob_start();
    get_template_part( 'test-one' );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('test2', 'test_2');
```

---

```
function test_2( $attr ) {
    ob_start();
    get_template_part( 'wp-content/themes/theme-name/template-parts/test-one' );
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('test2', 'test_2');
```

Template part code is

```
<?php

echo "Current as of <br>  ".date("m-d-Y h:i:sa");
```

Seems like it should work, no? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't include `wp-content` in the parameters either, `'test', 'one'` was correct. When you say that it doesn't work, can you be more specifiic? The shortcode is not added? The shortcode works but there is no  output? PHP fatal error? It's unclear what it's doing if it's not doing what you expected, or how you're testing this

Comment: I also see you have ` the shortcode tag of res-1` is this a broken comment? Or text that's not meant to be in there? Your code as is would  generate a PHP syntax  error due to the missing `//` at the start of the comment

Comment: @tomJNowell Sorry left over from a comment I removed most of

Comment: For 'test' 'one' without any path, it simply shows the name of the shortcode in the shortcode box, doesnt do anything. Yes page is published, theme doesnt matter, have switched that too.

Comment: Then the contents of your shortcode are irrelevant, it isn't being registered, where is the code that registers your shortcode located? You're using `[test2]` not `[test_2]` right?

Comment: @tomjnowell thanks. Test_2 is the name of function, the shortcode name is test2 to call it. I have tested it with content of my other shortcodes to make sure it is being called. My other shortocdes are not Get Template based. Point is I know that the shortcode call is good

Comment: If you're seeing the shortcode unprocessed on the frontend then clearly, ***it is not***. Where is the code that calls `add_shortcode` located? Please confirm the location of your code snippet in your codebase. Don't insist we take it on faith when you can demonstrate that it's being called correctly. Otherwise there is no mechanism in PHP for `get_template_part` to influence `add_shortcode` in the way you're suggesting it does.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem by using your code with a renamed function and `get_template_part( 'test' )`, `add_shortcode( 'test', 'shortcode_test_func' );`, and `[test]`. The shortcode worked first time, your problem could not be replicated. I placed my shortcode in a plugin file `shortcodetest.php` in my plugins folder. If your shortcode was registered, you would not see the shortcode square brackets on the frontend. You ***must*** be calling `add_shortcode` in an incorrect place. If this is not the case, prove it to us by sharing how you're calling it, and the file

Comment: @TomJnowell thanks. I am calling it in the same way the code is above. The same order. It is inside a customshortcodes.php file that is correctly called since the rest of the codes inside that file are being called just fine. None are get template codes other than this one which is not working. So i know it is being called correctly. I have also replaced the contents of the test2 shortcode with something else to prove its called correctly and that works. The only thing that doesnt work is calling a shortcode with a gettemplate. Is there something I can provide or show which would help?

Comment: And `customshortcodes.php` is being loaded from `functions.php` or is this in a plugin? Is it running on a hook? If it's displaying the `[test2]` text as is on the frontend then something has gone wrong somewhere and it doesn't recognise it as a shortcode, so your function with `get_template_part` isn't being called to begin with. I'm assuming other shortcodes work in the same area this is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_template_part()` function doesn't assume any directory name, you have to explicitly supply it. It's also relative to the active theme directory. So in many of your examples it was looking for the template in the root of your active theme. The correct format would be:

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/test-one' );
```

If you wanted to, you could rename the folder to `inc` or `includes` - it's arbitrary. You just need to reflect this change in the function call.

---

On a side note, WordPress does allow you to pass a 2nd parameter and will look for files joined by a dash. For example, this will also work:

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/test', 'one' );
```

The benefit of this is it allows you to have multiple "types" of a specific part. You may have a `content-post.php` file to output your post content and a `content-page.php` to output your page content. Then in your theme you *could* call your template by:

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', $post->post_type );
```

Just allows it to be a bit more dynamic.

---

Another side note. Any time you have trouble with these kinds of functions you can always use:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    $template = locate_template( $template_string_here );
    printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $template, 1 ) );
    die( 'end' );
} );
```

This will output the template path WordPress is trying to access the template by.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111889/discussion-on-answer-by-howdy-mcgee-template-part-inside-shortcode-unexpected-r).